# Tailwind CSS flexbox gap is not working on iPhone Chrome

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am facing some problem with CSS flexbox gap. Why it is not working on iPhone?
[image]

Here's my code

```
<div className="flex flex-col gap-2">
```

on desktop
[image]

on iphone chrome
[image]

Comment: You seem to have answered your question by showing the caniuse info for IOS Safari which gives 'not implemented'. Could you explain a bit more what the scenario is if you feel this isn't the cause of the problem?

Comment: I don't get it. Do you mean IOS Safari and IOS Chrome having the same compatibility?

Comment: iOS Safari and Chrome both use the same version of Webkit, which is only updated with new versions of iOS.

Answer (score 18):

You can achieve spacing on Tailwind flexbox with `space-` classes.

```
<div className="flex flex-col space-x-4">
```

By the way; applying `gap` class names on Tailwind flexbox is not a generic method. Gap sizing works only with `grid` containers.

```
<div className="grid gap-1 grid-cols-2">
```

Comment: What do you mean not possible? https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-cra-forked-c6ft2?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Regarding to Tailwind documentation; the proper way for columns spacing is using  `space between` notation on flexbox elements. 

[Space Between - Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/space)

Comment: I had the same problem with Safari. Can confirm that `space between` works. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/space

Comment: Gap sizing for flexbox has been available at least since Tailwind v2: https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/gap This is a problem with Safari versions lower than 14.5 and any browser on iOS that still has < 14.5 (they all use the same installed version of Webkit).

Answer (score 1):

Currently, 'space-' is the best workaround for replacing gaps however you only need to do that for your flex gaps, grid gaps work perfectly fine on iOS, so if you are going to refactor you don't have to refactor your grids at least.